# What are my friends' names? (A visual puzzle)

Tags: word, wordplay, visual, rebus, science

While messing around at one evening, I made six small drawings, one for each friend of mine.

My drawings were made to be very specific: Taking the action or object represented in any of them, you can rip out all the non-alphabetic characters, then discard one letter to yield the respective friend's first name.

For example, if I had drawn something like this:

[image: PuzzleExample]

You could expect it's talking about marriage, so "marry" would be the action, yielding, among some unusual names, "Mary". Happily, all my friends' names are in what is considered the "normal" spectrum.

Can you guess their names only from the drawings below?

**Friend 1:**

> [image: Puzzle 0]

**Friend 2:**

> [image: Puzzle 1]

**Friend 3:**

> [image: Puzzle 2]

**Friend 4:**

> [image: Puzzle 3]

**Friend 5:**

> [image: Puzzle 4]

**My greatest friend (And love):**

> [image: Puzzle 5]

Note: The order has changed because of one drawing that I forgot to add to the list.

Comment: Can't understand if in N°2 there is a ribbon or a fly :(

Comment: In N°2, is there a butterfly or a bow tie?

Comment: N°1 is clearly a leash and bow on an invisible dog.  Not sure what name that implies, but pretty sure that's the intent... (I assume you both meant that?  N°2 is not anything like a ribbon, fly, etc.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well... I had to economize considering my limited time and drawing skills...

Comment: The first one gives me "outhouse" instead of "marriage"

Comment: The butterfly thing is a bow. @Alex It's possible

Comment: Wait, the invisible dog is at N°2 now.  Did you add one before it?  (Never mind, just saw the comment that the order had changed...)

Comment: Is number one "what's-his-face?"  I think that would qualify as "commonly used", at least in the US... ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For number two:

> The invisible dog comment is spot on.  But because the dog is not
>  there, what you are left seeing is the leash.  Drop an S and you get:
>  **Leah**.

For number three:

> I think that Gordon K went too far.  It shows an atom, and dropping
>  one letter gives us a very "normal" name: **Tom**.

---

For number five:

> It seems pretty apparent from the drawing that the K is transparent. 
>  In other words, a "clear K".  Drop the E and you have: **Clark**.

---

For number four:

> You are putting the R in the E can. In other words, "can the R in E". 
>  Lose the first N and you have: **Catherine**.

Comment: Both correct. Congratulations!

Comment: One more, also correct. Keep going!

Comment: Three down, three to go :)

Answer (score 4):

Number 2 shows:

> An atom of hydrogen with an electron **A**, a proton **B** and uncertainty over whether there is a neutron **C**. The verb could be analyze stable hydrogen isotopes (ASHI) and dropping the letter 'i' gives ***Ash***. *Ok, I know this is a bit of a stretch.*

Number 4 shows:

> 'K' on a disc, so the verb would be 'disc K'. Drop the letter 's' to get ***Dick***.

Comment: Is Dick a common first name in the US? Searching it only yields the surname which is most common in Scotland

Comment: "Dick" was a popular nickname for "Richard" among the 50 years and older crowd in the U.S., kind of like "Chuck" (from "Charles") and "Betsy" (from "Elizabeth").

Answer (score 4):

Hmm this isn't used commonly as a first name but...

> It looks like an unknown object on top of something. So the question to be asked is "What's on?". Take away the 'h' and you've got WATSON

Comment: Well done.  I feel like the others I was close to, but I never would have gotten this.

Answer (score 3):

For 1, I think that:

> It's a net "catching" a butterfly so the action is "catch" and the friend's name is "Cath"

For 5 I wonder if:

> The friend's name is Meg - from "Mega" (Million).  I have no sensible logic to explain why the action is a "Million" though, so probably wrong.

Comment: #5 Left cube is 10X10X10 so 1000. Each subcube expands to the right cube which also is 1000. And `no`, there is no further subdivision. 1000X1000=million, so your hunch seems correct.

Comment: Nice explanation @KlasLindbäck - before you said that the meaning of the "no" had got me stumped

Comment: Or it's mega-No, which is "Megan" when you lose the "o".

Comment: I have a slight feeling that f'' is correct

Comment: It must be very inconvenient to catch butterflies with a net like this, though

Answer (score 2):

My guess for 5 is

> Nom, because [one millionth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-) is prefixed by *mu*, so "No mu" becomes Nom.

Comment: You are using the correct reasoning, just the other way around. Take a look at my new clue about #5

Comment: Though currently it is #6

Answer (score 2):

for the new friend number 1 I'm thinking,

> Bo, it looks like a box to me and drop the x you get Bo which is a usual name here in the south.

Comment: Not anymore, though :)

Answer (score 2):

The rounded corners on #1 make it look a bit like

> a television

So perhaps the name is

> Elly (i.e., "telly" without the "t")?

Comment: All right, I edited the box shape so it's not misleading people by association with common everyday things

Answer (score 1):

Is 5...

> Maximillian? It's the opposite ("no") of "mini millionth".

Comment: Good catch about the "million", but this puzzle does not require you to change letters, only delete them. "Maximillian" changes the "o" in million to an "a".

Answer (score -1):

Joining the 'million' train of thought. Is the answer to number 5:

> Milli?

Comment: Milli is two letters shorter, you are allowed to remove only one